# Ubuntu installation help wanted

Tags: system-installation, windows-vista

I have an old laptop with 2GB of RAM and an old Intel processor running 2 versions of Vista, one of which won't load and says it requires the repair CD and the other has a partition called Recovery (C:) I don't know much about computers, but I'm trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 on that laptop. Ubuntu launches and I can run it from a live CD. After doing a scan it says there are no bad files on the CD, but when I try to install Ubuntu it shows the loading bit after I've chosen my network (wifi), but seems to make no progress. Are the things I said at the start the problem?

Comment: File/drive not ogle

Comment: When I clicked computer it had the hard drive and recovery

Comment: The part of your question where you said "on the CD" is worrisome. The current versions of Ubuntu are too small to fit on a CD, so you have to use either a DVD or a USB flash drive to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Recovery partition might be too small. You need to shrink the main drive where Windows is installed to make room for Ubuntu.

Tip: You can install Ubuntu  without having to connect to the Internet. Not only is it faster, it saves you from having issues while installing. A number of times my Ubuntu installation was going nowhere because either (1) the download was too slow (if you ticked options where it would pull additional packages from the Ubuntu repos), or (2) installing these packages from the repos were causing issues in the background, that the installation never finishes. Good luck :)

Comment: I'm not good with computers and don't get what your getting at plz can you tell me exactly what to do in a simple way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked for an explanation in a simple way, so I am repeating what everybody said in a simpler way.

1. Alvar's comment: Use an answer for a guide that has a lot of pictures in it, so that it will be easier to understand. Like the one in [Alvar's link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).
2. My comment: Ubuntu is too small to fit on a CD, so you need to use either a DVD or a USB pen drive to install Ubuntu on your laptop.
3. Marky's comment: Give yourself **enough space** on the hard drive to put the new Ubuntu operating system. The Ubuntu installer will ask you if you want to split some space from the Vista partition and then you can install Ubuntu on that space. It will tell you how much space you need. Marky also said that you don't need an internet connection when you install Ubuntu, and the Ubuntu installation will go faster without the internet connection.